# iCloud Keychain search on iOS

Tags: ios, icloud, security

Am I just not seeing a way to search my iCloud keychain when I go to (iOS)
Settings>Safari>Passwords & AutoFill>Saved Passwords
?

The list is very long and they don't even give me a way to navigate quickly down the alphabet. I'm hoping that if search *isn't* currently available, they are going to add it soon.

Comment: This can be done if you're willing to jailbreak and learn SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you are right, you can't search in that list on iOS.

Though you can [give Apple some feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) and suggest them this particular feature.

Comment: Thanks, and done (again... though perhaps they don't remove duplicates if they are worded differently)